# Javascript Complex RegEx with variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this tool to build a regex http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex

I found that the one below works for me if, for example, I am looking to match `$aazz[AB]`:

```
var regex = /[\+\=\-\*\^\\]\$aazz\[AB\]/g;
```

I have read the other posts on the RegEx constructor in Javascript but cannot manage to make the following work:

```
var preToken = "[\+\=\-\*\^\\]";    
var toFind = "\$aazz\[AB\]";

var stringToReplace = "/" + preToken + toFind + "/";

var regex = new RegExp(stringToReplace, "g");
```

Here is the jsbin http://jsbin.com/ifeday/3/edit

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating regular expressions from strings, you need to escape your backslashes twice.

```
\ becomes \\
\\ becomes \\\\
```

So, you can try (in a character class not everything needs escaping):

```
var preToken = "[+=\\-*^\\\\]"; 
var toFind = "azz\\[A\\]";
```

Also, the string source for your regular expression does not need to be bound by `/`s, but I see in your jsBin that you've already corrected that.

Update your jsBin with these variable declarations, it should work now.